# getting output and exit status from shell_exec()

Tags: php

When doing something like

```
$output = shell_exec("command 2>&1");
```

collecting the command's stdout & stderr in `$output`, is there a way to find the command's exit status?

One could write the command output to a temp file and then append the exit status, but that's rather clunky. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As you've already seen, when using shell_exec you have to chain your "real" command with echo $? to get the exit status:

```
 $output_including_status = shell_exec("command 2>&1; echo $?");
```

but if you want the clean way, then you want to use the [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function, which allows a 3rd agument explicitly for this purpose.

Answer (score 14):

Following worked for me with `exec()` to show the output

```
exec(your_command, $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`popen()`](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) (+ manual handling of the process) instead.