# shell_exec doesn't execute from PHP but works fine in shell

Tags: php, shell-exec, inkscape

```
user/bin/inkscape -f sample.svg -e sample.png
```

Above command works when executes in shell, but with php shell_exec() its not executing.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Add `2>&1` for redirecting stderr to stdout to see if there where any errors.

Comment: $command = "/user/bin/inkscape -f sample.svg -e sample.png";

shell_exec($command); 

this is my code and how can I use 2>&1 ?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec) might help you