# return curl code in php

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am trying to find out if a curl call was successful or not in php, the equivalent in bash would be:

```
`eval curl -f --data $payload http://localhost/service`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo passed
else
    echo failed
fi
```

so far I have this in php but it does not work:

```
    `eval curl -f --data $PAYLOAD "http://localhost/service"`;
    if ( $? == 0 )
        echo fail;
    else
        echo passed;
```

however I get the following error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

the payload looks like the folioing:

```
    $PAYLOAD="'payload={ 
    \"firstname\":\"$firstname\",
    \"id\":\"$id\", 
    \"author_lastname\":\"$lastname\"
    }' "
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `$?` is not a valid variable identifier. Your entire PHP code is everything but valid PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user2405162 mentioned it'd be better to use PHP's curl library, but if you really want to use shell instead, do it like this:

```
exec("curl -f --data $PAYLOAD \"http://localhost/service\"", $output, $status);
// constant on left side, to catch assignment 
// instead of comparison typos
if ( 0 == $status )
    echo "fail";
else
    echo "passed";
```

Backquote syntax only returns output in PHP, no status code is provided. Yet you can try some workarounds:

```
$status = `curl -f --data $payload http://localhost/service > /dev/null; echo $?`
if ( $status == 0 )
    echo "fail";
else
    echo "passed";
```

As mentioned in this question: [getting output and exit status from shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec)

Comment: this almost works! But I am seeing errors like :  eval: id:40,: not found, sh: 21: eval: type:11,: not found - these are fields in the payload, the payload worked fine in my example above

Comment: Can you post contents of the $payload variable?

Comment: sure, i have added it to the question above

Comment: it's the eval causing the issue, removing it fixes the problem, but i do need the status of that curl call ...

Comment: So use exec without eval - command status is saved to it's third argument.

Comment: working now, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use PHP's curl library?

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Then you can use the built in error functions to catch exceptions.