# shell_exec with manually installed commands

Tags: php

I cannot seem to get this to work:

```
shell_exec("/anaconda/bin/scrapy crawl script_v5 -a calln=D5 -o output_D5.csv");
```

I suspect commands manually installed don't work.

In addition, I was trying to dump the $PATH to know where it searches, but

```
shell_exec("echo $PATH");
```

returns NULL.

Why is this so, and how do I solve it?

By the way, I ran the script from a browser calling to localhost where MAMP is running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec

Comment: Is it allowed to execute `shell_exec()`?

Comment: @OleHaugset How is the link relevant?

Comment: @TobiasF. Yes it returns output like "echo hello" or "type echo" perfectly.

Comment: Since you are using double quotes, `$PATH` will be interpreted as a PHP variable, it will not reference your OS' `$PATH` system variable.

Comment: thank you @George for pointing that out. But how about the first line of code? It doesn't work. Is it because of permissions?

Comment: @humanitiesclinic I'm afraid I could only speculate, but permissions would be my first assumption, yes. (Assuming you can run this script without issue using command line)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the server disabled this function because of high-risk security issue

```
shell_exec();
```

so you should read the file and then get your output.
using

```
fopen()
```