# soffice command not execute in php shell_exec()

Tags: php, soffice

I have run this command in `shell_exe()` function as shown below:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/soffice --headless --convert-to html:HTML --outdir /home/admin/Desktop/ /home/admin/Desktop/text.docx');
```

But it gives me error like this in apache error log:

> Error: Please reverify input parameters...

Comment: Just to clarify: Does this command work *on the server*?

Comment: @xanoetux yes this command works fine.

Comment: Maybe safe mode is active?

Comment: @xanoetux safe mode is not active.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have received is not PHP / apache related.

It is an `soffice` output.

So `shell_exec()` works without problems even the executed command returned an output that was passed back to the `shell_exec()` function.

How to run `soffice` I recommend search forums like: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

To receive the error output is better to use `exec()` function instead of `shell_exec()`

[getting output and exit status from shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15264/executing-a-shell-command-from-php-with-shell-exec

Comment: This error is coming from php. I have seen in apache error log. ```soffice``` command works well in terminal directly.

Comment: Try redirecting the error output to the standard output using `2>&1`

Comment: The same error is being displayed in browser which is shown in error.log.

Comment: Still the error is coming from soffice.. not from PHP. Apache only deliver the message from CLI back to your application and print it.

Comment: But how can you know that error is coming from soffice not from php. Please let me know.

Comment: Read the answer above and click on the first url to get more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161083/discussion-between-jigar-pancholi-and-ino).