# I can run curl from command line but can't call from shell exec

Tags: php, windows, curl

I want to use `shell_exec` to run `curl` and get the response.
The problem is that my shell exec command doesn't work when I run `curl`, it works fine when I run `curl` in `cmd` or `cygwin`.
I'm using laravel 5.6 with php 7.2

I can run:

> shell_exec("ping domain.com");

It return response like it has used to.

But I can't run:

> shell_exec("curl some thing here");

It gives me `null` when I use `dd()` or blank when I `print_r()`.

- My curl version 7.61 windows 10 64bit, open ssl 1.1.0i
- Already set path system variable on environment

I know I can use guzzle, but I am just wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: I removed the `laravel` tag as the question is not related to laravel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec

Comment: @RossWilson http://puu.sh/Bf5l8/a597508cd3.png i got error message like that, wondering why i run from cmd , and error message cygwin ?

Comment: You should use the full path for `curl`. If you run `which curl` you should see the full path.

Comment: @Jim: Newbie User has a MSWindows box - `which` won't work.

Comment: I suspect Jim is right though - PHP can't find the executable. Try the full path, make sure your error reporting is working and check the return code / sttderr from the command.

Comment: @symcbean Good point, I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [PHP Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) (IT's necessary to enable PHP curl extension). It's a safer way *- You dont need to access shell + on many shared hostings, it's disabled -* and also works natively under Windows.

The problem you are fighting off is caused probably by missing PATH. That's why it works in cygwin, not under native shell. Note that PHP execs in native shell.

Comment: well combining ur answer and jim wright about pathing, i realize which part wrong that's my pathing had typo there, thats why i can't run which curl
thank you !