# How to execute a python script in php with a shell command?

Tags: php, python, html

I want to execute my python script (/var/www/html/start.py) in my php script (/var/www/html/index.php) with the code below:

```php
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

    <?php
    shell_exec("python /var/www/html/start.py");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The command works in the terminal and the python code is fine. I also tried to put the code in an external php script. No errors are shown.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["/home/pi/pipresents/pipresents.py", "-p", "pp_mediashow"])
```

I am working with an raspberry pi and apache2 to show the index.php on web. I installed PHP 7.3.

Comment: check if this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086572/php-how-to-get-shell-errors-echoed-out-to-screen

Comment: No, there no informations which could help me.

Comment: you do not get any errors? write what the python script does

Comment: please edit your question with all informations, do not writing in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Create in sudoers premissions for **www-data** user and allow run python for that user.

https://serverfault.com/questions/482502/how-to-set-up-sudo-rights-for-execution-of-python-script-from-php

And
[getting output and exit status from shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941755/getting-output-and-exit-status-from-shell-exec)